# How to solve and analyze a system of 15 equations with 15 variables?

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, difference-equations, system

I have a system of $15$ equations and $15$ key variables. Some of the equations are non-linear. Some constant variables in the equation can be equal to numbers to solve the system. I have to find a positive solution for the key variables and then analyze the impact of constant variables on the key variables. Here is the system of equations:

```
theta - b * qiG = w + etaG * md
theta - b * qiB = phi0 - phi1 * NB + alphaB * p
theta - b * qiB = phi0 - phi1 * NB + alphaB * p
theta0G - b * qtheta0G = w + etaG * md
thetaGB - b * qthetaGBG = w + etaG * md
thetaGB - b * qthetaGBB = phi0 - phi1 * NB + alphaB * p
1 - b * qthetaB1 = phi0 - phi1 * NB + alphaB * p
(theta0G - w - etaG * md) * qtheta0G - b/2 * qiG^2 - fG = 0
(thetaGB - w - etaG * md) * qthetaGBG - b/2 * qthetaGBG^2 - fG = (thetaGB - phi0 + phi1 * NB - alphaB * p) * qthetaGBB - b/2 * qthetaGBB^2 - fB
cb * Qb = p - etab * md
cg * Qg = p
p = A - B * QE
Qb + Qg = QE + alphaB * IntqiB
QG = IntqiG
phi1 * IntqiB = fN * NB
u0G = [theta0G - w - etaG * md] * qtheta0G - b/2 * qtheta0G^2
uGBG = [thetaGB - w - etaG * md] * qthetaGBG - b/2 * qthetaGBG^2
uGBB = [thetaGB - phi0 + phi1 * NB - alphaB * p] * qthetaGBB - b/2 * qthetaGBB^2
```

Here is the code in Mathematica:

```
qiG =.
qiB =.
qtheta0G =.
qthetaGBG =.
qthetaGBB =.
qthetaB1 =.
theta0G =.
thetaGB =.
Qb =.
Qg =.
QE =.
NB =.
QG =.
p =.
IntqiB =.
u0G =.
uGBG =.
uGBB =.
theta =.
q =.

(* Variable ranges *)
b = [0.1,2]
w = [0,2]
etaG = [0,2]
phi0 = [0,2]
phi1 = [0,2]
alphaB = [0,2]
md = [0.1,2]
fG = [0.1,2]
fB = [0.1,2]
fN = [0.1,2]
cb = [0.01,2]
cg = [0.01,2]
etab = [0.1,2]
A = [0,2]
B = [0.1,2]

(* Solutions *)
Sol1 = Solve[theta - b*q == w + etaG*md, q]
Sol2 = Solve[theta - b*q == phi0 - phi1*NB + alphaB*p, q]
"qiG:"
qiG = q /. Sol1[[1]]
"qiB:"
qiB = q /. Sol2[[1]]

Sol3a = Solve[theta0G - b*q == w + etaG*md, q]
"qtheta0G:"
qtheta0G = q /. Sol3a[[1]]

Sol3b = Solve[thetaGB - b*q == w + etaG*md, q]
"qthetaGBG:"
qthetaGBG = q /. Sol3b[[1]]

Sol4a = Solve[thetaGB - b*q == phi0 - phi1*NB + alphaB*p, q]
"qthetaGBB:"
qthetaGBB = q /. Sol4a[[1]]

Sol4b = Solve[1 - b*q == phi0 - phi1*NB + alphaB*p, q]
"qthetaB1:"
qthetaB1 = q /. Sol4
(* Variable Costs *)
"cG"
cG  = w + etaG*md
"cB"
cB = phi0/(1 + NB) + alphaB*p

(* Utilities *)
"u0G:"
u0G = (theta0G - w - etaG*md)*qtheta0G - b*qtheta0G^2/2 // FullSimplify
"uGBG:"
uGBG = (thetaGB - w - etaG*md)*qthetaGBG - b*qthetaGBG^2/2 // FullSimplify
"uGBB:"
uGBB = (thetaGB - phi0 + phi1*NB - alphaB*p)*qthetaGBB -b*qthetaGBB^2/2 // FullSimplify

(* two thetas *)
Sol5 = Solve[u0G == fG, theta0G] 
"theta0G:"
theta0G = theta0G /. Sol5[[2]]


Sol6 = Solve[uGBG - fG == uGBB - fB, thetaGB]
"thetaGB:"
thetaGB = thetaGB /. Sol6[[1]]

(* Energy *)
"Qb:"
Qb = (p + etab*md)/cb
"Qg:"
Qg = p/cg
"QE:"
QE = (A - p)/B
"QG:"
QG = Integrate [qiG, {theta, theta0G, thetaGB} ] // FullSimplify

(* Integral *)
"IntqiB:"
IntqiB = Integrate[qiB, {theta, thetaGB, 1}]  // FullSimplify

(* Network Size *)
"NB:"
NB =.
Sol7 = Solve[phi1*IntqiB == fN*NB, NB]
NB = NB /. Sol7[[1]]


(* price *)
Sol8 = FindRoot[Qb + Qg == QE + alphaB*IntqiB, {p, 0}]
p = p /. Sol8[[1]]
```

We must solve the model to find a "positive number" for the key variables. If it is not possible at first, we can fix a key variable (like NB) at the first step, then solve the model based on the fixed parameter, and finally solve the fixed parameter based on the solution of the model.
Then, we need to analyze the impact of constant variables on each equation (Sensitivity Analysis) and use functions like "Manipulate" to analyze this impact.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me find a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Moi! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: `b = [0.1,2]` isn't valid Mathematica syntax.

Comment: Perhaps start a small experiment with `Assuming[1<=b<=2&&0<=w<=2&&...,
Sol1=Reduce[theta-b*q==w+etaG*md,q];Print[Sol1];]` and see what you get. Then you can expand the experiment a little bit and try it again.

Comment: Your equations are not equations. You cannot use `Set` (i.e., `=`) in place of `Equal` (i.e., `==`). Also, function brackets cannot be used as parentheses. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. See how much of your problem this solves and whether you can use this to finish the problem.

```
Reduce[1/10<=b<=2&&0<=w<=2&&0<=etaG<=2&&0<=phi0<=2&&0<=phi1<=2&&0<=alphaB<=2&&
  1/10<=md<=2&&1/10<=fG<=2&&1/10<=fB<=2&&1/10<=fN<=2&&1/100<=cb<=2&&
  1/100<=cg<=2&&1/10<=etab<=2&&0<=A<=2&&1/10<=B<=2&&theta-b*qiG==w+etaG*md&&
  theta-b*qiB==phi0-phi1*NB+alphaB*p&&theta0G-b*qtheta0G==w+etaG*md&&
  thetaGB-b*qthetaGBG==w+etaG*md&&thetaGB-b*qthetaGBB==phi0-phi1*NB+alphaB*p&&
  thetaB1==phi0-phi1*NB+alphaB*p&&cG==w+etaG*md&&cB==phi0/(1+NB)+alphaB*p&&
  u0G==(theta0G-w-etaG*md)*qtheta0G-b*qtheta0G^2/2&&
  uGBG==(thetaGB-w-etaG*md)*qthetaGBG-b*qthetaGBG^2/2&&
  uGBB==(thetaGB-phi0+phi1*NB-alphaB*p)*qthetaGBB-b*qthetaGBB^2/2, 
  {qiG,qiB,qtheta0G,qthetaGBG,qthetaGBB,cG,cB,u0G,uGBG,uGBB},Reals]/.
  {Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,fG,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,fB,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,fN,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/100,LessEqual,cb,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/100,LessEqual,cg,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,etab,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,A,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,B,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,md,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[1/10,LessEqual,b,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,w,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,thetaB1,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,phi0,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,phi1,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,etaG,LessEqual,2]->True,
   Inequality[0,LessEqual,alphaB,LessEqual,2]->True}
```

That imposes your domain constraints, finds multiple solutions for some of your equations, and then removes the constraints before displaying the results so that you can try to understand. Perhaps you can add more conditions so that it will only find the solution that you desire.

Please check this very carefully to see if I have made any mistakes.